# C# Gmail settings set POP3 enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail, pop3

Hy,

I am retrieving mails from a gmail account programaticaly using this libraries http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/ .

Everything it's OK (I get the messages count and a list of all messages) when I run my application for the first time after I set the 'Enable POP for all mail' to OK in the 'Forwarding and POP/IMAP' tab in Settings menu. But when I run it again no messages are being retrieved. And if I go again and set the enable POP for all mail, the application works again.

I think I have to set 'enable POP for all mail' programaticaly before I run the retrieving messages code.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do this programaticaly in C# and asp.net?

The code I'm using:

```
Pop3Client pop = new Pop3Client();
        try
        {
            Label7.Text = string.Format("Connection to the pop 3 server : {0}", "pop.gmail.com ");
            pop.ConnectSsl("pop.gmail.com", 995, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text);

            Label7.Text += string.Format("Message Count: {0}", pop.MessageCount.ToString());
            MessageCollection mc = new MessageCollection();
            for (int n = 1; n < pop.MessageCount + 1; n++)
            {
                Message newMessage = pop.RetrieveMessageObject(n);
                mc.Add(newMessage);

                 Label7.Text += string.Format("Message ({0}) : {1} ", n.ToString(), newMessage.Subject);
            }
        }

        catch (Pop3Exception pexp)
        {
            Label7.Text = string.Format("Pop3 Error: {0} ", pexp.Message);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label7.Text = string.Format("Failed: {0} ", ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            if (pop.IsConnected)
            {
                pop.Disconnect();
            }
        }
```

And I'm using the ActiveUp.Net.Mail library from the source I've mentioned before.

Comment: Which options are you picking for questions 1 and 2 under POP?  For Q1 you probably should pick the first option - enable POP for all mail (even that's already been downloaded) and for Q2 you probably want to choose the first one - "keep Gmail's copy in the Inbox".

Comment: Yes, but I how can I do this programatically in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get the **[IMAP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol)** behavior with **[POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol)**?

With **POP3**, the email is usually deleted from the server once retrieved. Then only new messages will become available in your application the next time you connext. And so on.

With **IMAP4**, the messages remains on the server. It's a different approach. You have to maintain a state locally that will synchronize with your **IMAP4** server.

Comment: That is what I don't understand... why I cannot retrieve the same mails with pop3 when I run the application the second time, the third time and so on. My gmail account is configured with pop.gmail.com at incoming mail server.

Comment: I think it's some logic Gmail provide to prevent client from downloading 2 times the same message between 2 sessions. If you really want to download multiple times the same message, opt for IMAP4

Comment: hmmm... I've tried with IMAP4 but isn't working (and that is logic because my incoming mail server is pop.gmail.com, POP3). Is there any other way to retrieve the same messages in 2 sessions?

Comment: Yes don't use gmail, use another POP3 server instead

Comment: I have the same question, is there still no real answers, how to enable pop programaticaly?